# UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed in a lightning community is returning theme3

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, userinfo

I have a lightning component thats used in LEX, Classic, and a community. The component redirects the user to a record detail page after an action occurs. I am trying to implement `UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()` to redirect the user to the correct place depending on the UI theme they are on.

However, in the lightning community it's returning theme3 as the value, I am expecting PortalDefault or Theme4d in the correct [themes list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm)

Component:

```
var locationAction = component.get('c.getLocationTheme');
locationAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    console.log('Location: ' + response.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(locationAction);
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getLocationTheme() {
    return UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplayed();
}
```

Debug:
`Location: Theme3`

Is this expected behavior? What is the correct way of knowing where your lightning component instance is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up just writing my own method to get around it.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getLocationTheme() {
    if (Site.getSiteId() != null) {
        return COMMUNITY;
    } else if (UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme3') {
        return CLASSIC;
    } else {
        return LEX;
    }
}
```